# WPF WndProc is call more then one time

Tags: c#, wpf

Why the WndProc get called multiple times, when a device is plug in, for example USB, the WndProc is called four times:

```
 protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
            IntPtr windowHandle = (new WindowInteropHelper(this)).Handle;
            HwndSource src = HwndSource.FromHwnd(windowHandle);
            src.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
        }

        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
            {
// Handle WM_DEVICECHANGE
            if (msg == 0x0219)
            {
```

Thank you

Comment: not sure. because when the usb is unplugged, it only called once. each devices will call different times.

Comment: How to fix this problem. ?

Answer (score 0):

yes it does so, however you may notice different  `wParam` & `lParam`. For every event `WndProc` will receive message from OS. The other parameter values after `msg` will let you know the context in which they are raised.

Comment: when a usb is plug in, the int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam is all the same. wParam is 7 and lParam is 0.